# How to make a relationship with identity on .net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

i need a help! I am using Identity on my application and i've created an ApplicationUser : IdentityUser with some more properties such as fullname, address and company.

I've also created an entity called Donation that is related one-to-one with campaign and i need to make one-to-one with the user too but i don't know how to make this, especially because i am using two different contexts and they are on each one.

Below the codes

**ApplicationUser class**

```c#
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; } 
        
        // RELATIONS
        public IEnumerable<Donate> Donations { get; set; } --> It's not working on migration
    }
```

**Donation class**

```c#
    public class Donate 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        public Campagin Campaign { get; set; } 
        public Guid CampaignId { get; set; } 

        // RELATIONS
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; } --> It is not working on migration
        public Guid UserId { get; set; } 
    }
```

**IdentityContext**

```c#
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) 
            : base(options) { }
    }
```

**EntitiesContext**

```c#
    public class DoadoresDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DoadoresDbContext(DbContextOptions<DoadoresDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Donate> Donations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(e => e.GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string))))
                property.SetColumnType("varchar(100)");

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DoadoresDbContext).Assembly);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("DataCadastro") != null))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCadastro").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCadastro").IsModified = false;
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "It's not working on migration" - What exactly does that mean? What errors do you get?

Comment: It is happening something wrong with foreign key, userId.

Comment: If you already have data in the dependent table (the one with FK - `Donate`), the FK must be made optional, e,g. `Guid` -> `Guid?`